# How to build a URI using URIbuilder without encoding hash

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, uribuilder

I have a URI like this:

`java.net.URI location = UriBuilder.fromPath("../#/Login").queryParam("token", token).build();`

and I am sending it as response: `return Response.seeOther(location).build()`

However, in the above URI, `#` is getting encoded to `%23/`. How do I create a URI with out encoding the hash `#`. According to [official document](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs-javax.jax-rs/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html), a `fragment()` method must be used to keep unencoded.

> URI templates are allowed in most components of a URI but their value
>   is restricted to a particular component. E.g.
>
> > UriBuilder.fromPath("{arg1}").build("foo#bar"); would result in
> >     encoding of the '#' such that the resulting URI is "foo%23bar". To
> >     create a URI "foo#bar" use
> >     UriBuilder.fromPath("{arg1}").fragment("{arg2}").build("foo", "bar") instead.

Looking at the example from docs, I am not sure how to apply it in my case.

The final URI should look like this:

`http://localhost:7070/RTH_Sample14/#Login?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvcnRoLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IlJUSCIsInJvbGUiOiJVU0VSIiwiZXhwIjoxNDU2Mzk4MTk1LCJlbWFpbCI6Imtpcml0aS5rOTk5QGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9.H3d-8sy1N-VwP5VvFl1q3nhltA-htPI4ilKXuuLhprxMfIx2AmZZqfVRUPR_tTovDEbD8Gd1alIXQBA-qxPBcxR9VHLsGmTIWUAbxbyrtHMzlU51nzuhb7-jXQUVIcL3OLu9Gcssr2oRq9jTHWV2YO7eRfPmHHmxzdERtgtp348`

Comment: why do you want to add a query param after the fragment? this does not make sense

Comment: @wero hmm sounds right but then how to send query params?

Comment: @wero added the final URI to question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To construct the URI with fragment use

```
UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:7070/RTH_Sample14/").fragment("Login").build()
```

This results in the URI string

```
http://localhost:7070/RTH_Sample14/#Login
```

---

But if you also add query parameters

```
UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:7070/RTH_Sample14/").fragment("Login")
          .queryParam("token", "t").build()
```

then the `UriBuilder` always inserts the query params before the fragment:

```
http://localhost:7070/RTH_Sample14/?token=t#Login
```

which simply complies to the URL syntax.

Comment: I fixed it in other way. What do you think is the best way? Check my answer below and thanks for taking time to answer my question

Comment: How can we get the fragment before query params?

Comment: greperror - The HTTP specification states that the server will ignore anything following a # character, so if you add params AFTER # they will only be visible client side (i.e in the browser/javascript/etc). Browsers can even chose not to send the part after #.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of all the hassle of redirecting without encoding the hash value. I changed my code into the following:

```
java.net.URI location = new java.net.URI("../#/Login?token=" + token);
```

So the query param above is token appended to URI location. In front-end I am using angular's `location.search().token` to get capture the query param.

This worked for me. Looking for better answers though. Thanks

Comment: UriBuilder helps with encoding and adding path parameters. If you don't need this (as in your example, since you **know** that token needs no encoding), this approach is fine. Although in the strict sense it does not answer your original question.

Comment: I think it does. I believe you have an Angular app that has a /#/ URL at the end and you want it to take a query param of your json web token. 
I had a similar problem. This works.

Comment: @kiran.gilvaz glad it helped

Comment: Any idea how I would do this for Android? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri